# filter array accoring to its nested array value

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have an array of results. I want to filter the results to an array whose `category`s have at least one object with a `cat_id` of `1`. How can I do that?

```
"results": [
  {
    "product_id": 1,
    "title": "booking",
    "draft": false,
    "publish": true,
    "category": [
      {
        "cat_id": 1,
        "cat_name": "web",
        "product": "booking"
      }
    ],
  },
  {
    "product_id": 2,
    "title": "reading",
    "draft": false,
    "publish": true,
    "category": [
      {
        "cat_id": 6,
        "cat_name": "android",
        "product": "asdasd"
      }
    ],
  },
  {
    "product_id": 3,
    "title": "reading",
    "draft": false,
    "publish": true,
    "category": [],
  },
]
```

My attempt:

```
for (let i = 0; i < data.results.length; i++) {
  this.webCatProducts = data.results[i].category.filter(d => d.cat_id == 1)
  console.log(this.webCatProducts)
}
```

Comment: yes it can be empty or have 3 objects that you can see above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.some` inside the `.filter` to check to see if any of the `category` objects have a matching`cat_id`:

```js
const results=[{"product_id":1,"title":"booking","draft":!1,"publish":!0,"category":[{"cat_id":1,"cat_name":"web","product":"booking"}],},{"product_id":2,"title":"reading","draft":!1,"publish":!0,"category":[{"cat_id":6,"cat_name":"android","product":"asdasd"}],},{"product_id":3,"title":"reading","draft":!1,"publish":!0,"category":[],},];
const filtered = results.filter(
  ({ category }) => category.some(({ cat_id }) => cat_id === 1)
);
console.log(filtered);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do filter on product level `results: []` and predicate matched with expected category’s id with nested find *some* like this; `.filter(product => product.category.some(cat => cat.cat_id === 1)`

*Make sure that category is always an array otherwise you have to check more*.